# Ruby - DateTime library parsing error (a bug?)

Tags: ruby, datetime, hash

Can someone verify my datetime conversion error.

What I have is a hash of days of the week as number fixnum keys generated from the Date library.  I sorted the hash and I want to convert the fixnum keys to days of the week (ie 0 --> Sunday)

My hash output is `{3=>7, 2=>1, 4=>2}` ( using `dh=Hash[dh.sort]` I would get `{2=>1, 3=>7, 4=>2}` )

after the sort, I try to perform a .each do

```
dh = {3=>7, 2=>1, 4=>2}
dh=Hash[dh.sort]

dh.each do |day,reg|
    #puts day.class
    #puts day="3" # This works

    day=day.to_s  ##<<== problem here: error "invalid date" when evaluated by strptime
                  ## if don't do day.to_s conversion, error "can't convert fixnum into string"
    #day="#{day}" ## does not work either

    wday= DateTime.strptime(day,'%d') ##<<== and problem here

    puts wday.strftime("%a")
    puts wday   
      end
```

so the `day` variable is a fixnum.  So no matter what I do to the day variable (convert to string, or leave it as fixnum), the strptime does not work.

It does not matter if I make up another variable such as `xyz = day.to_s`, the `xyz` variable would still get error out by the strptime method.

But if I manually assign the day variable a string value `day="3"`, then the strptime would work.

Any insight into this problem, is this a bug?

Comment: Could you simplify this so it is just one line and give the expected output vs the actual output?  Just saying "it does not work" does not work.

Comment: the interpreter errors out.  "can't convert fixnum into string..." or "invalid date"

Comment: Could you simplify to just one line?

Comment: @Jamex the above code works fine, you might need to add the interpreter error messages

Comment: What about `DateTime.strptime("3", "%d")` ?

Comment: @DavidGrayson, it works fine with "3"

Comment: @bjhaid, the main part of the error messages are stated in the code area, I can't/don't want to retype the whole error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do understand you correctly, you are confusing the proper datetime format. If you need to handle the *weekday number* you need to put `%w` instead of `%d` ie. day of the month.

```
dh = {3=>7, 2=>1, 4=>2, 0=>5}.sort
dh.each do |day,reg|
  day=day.to_s
  wday= DateTime.strptime(day,'%w')
  puts wday.strftime("%a")
end

# Sun
# Tue
# Wed
# Thu
```

Answer (score 0):

This work

```
=> dh = {3=>2, 2=>7}
=> {3=>2, 2=>7}
=> dh = Hash[dh.sort]
=> {2=>7, 3=>2}
=> dh.each { |day,reg| DateTime.strptime(day,'%d') }
=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
=> dh.each { |day,reg| puts DateTime.strptime(day.to_s,'%d') }
=> 2013-12-02T00:00:00+00:00
=> 2013-12-03T00:00:00+00:00
=> {2=>7, 3=>2}
```

Comment: Thanks, the original code works, but I found what I consider to be a design bug for date library. The strptime method does not recognize "0" as a valid day of the week (aka Sunday).  See my explanation (to come).

Answer (score 0):

Editted to reflect the correct cause pointed out.

OK, I figured out the problem

I originally used the

```
datestamp = DateTime.strptime(datestr, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

and the `datestamp.wday` to create a hash with #wday values as the keys.  These #wday values are numbers from 0-6 to represent Sunday-Saturday.

When I used the `DateTime.strptime(day,'%d')`, I should had used the %w switch. The correct statement should have been `DateTime.strptime(day.to_s,'%w')`